# Turning on/off .psd layers inside Blender

Tags: texturing, shaders, layers

Is it possible to turn on or off the visibility of specific layers on a .psd file from within Blender? Or better yet: pick Layer Comps within Blender.

I'm asking so that I might use a single .psd file containing everything from albedo, gloss, bump, normals, etc. (If I remember correctly, I could do this in Maya, though I never could get it to work perfectly.)

Thanks